# How can you use Google Colab TPU to save checkpoints to Google Cloud Storage in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, tpu

1. Scripts in Tensorflow 1.X,but it's still not working in **Tensorflow 2.0**

2.How can I migrate this scipts to **Tensorflow 2.0**

```
import datetime
import json
import os
import pprint
import random
import string
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

assert 'COLAB_TPU_ADDR' in os.environ, 'ERROR: Not connected to a TPU runtime; please see the first cell in this notebook for instructions!'
TPU_ADDRESS = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
print('TPU address is', TPU_ADDRESS)

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

with tf.compat.v1.Session(TPU_ADDRESS) as session:
  print('TPU devices:')
  pprint.pprint(session.list_devices())

  # Upload credentials to TPU.
  with open('/content/adc.json', 'r') as f:
    auth_info = json.load(f)
  tf.contrib.cloud.configure_gcs(session, credentials=auth_info)
#   Now credentials are set for all future sessions on this TPU.
```

Comment: **I get this error**:---tensorflow:InvalidArgumentError: Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 400 with body '{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bucket is requester pays bucket but no user project provided.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Bucket is requester pays bucket but no user project provided.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required"
      }
    ]
  }
}
'
  when reading metadata of gs://nq-competition//checkpoint

Comment: I had this issue and this helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61448884/how-to-connect-to-private-storage-bucket-using-the-google-colab-tpu though I am now running into a different issue